# `bookdown`/`rmarkdown`/`knitr`: YAML header elements dependent on `knitr::opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to')`?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, bookdown

Imagine a `bookdown` `yaml` header along the lines of:

```
---
title: Example
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: "function(..., number_sections) rmarkdown::beamer_presentation(...)"
    number_sections: yes
  bookdown::pdf_document2
geometry: margin=1in, a4paper
---
```

Compiling this works when using the `bookdown::pdf_document2` target, but fails with a `\usepackage{caption}` option clash for the `bookdown::pdf_book` target.

I would like to invoke the `geometry` header entry ONLY for the `bookdown::pdf_document2` target, but all experimentation with

```
!r ifelse(knitr::opts_knit$get('rmarkdown.pandoc.to') %in% c('beamer'), '', 'margin=1in, a4paper')
```

(with many iterations of `''`/`NA`/`'.na'`/`NULL`/`'null'` etc.) fails, as any empty setting for `geometry` still interferes.

I also could not find access to the `yaml` header content from the body of the `bookdown`/`rmarkdown` file (aiming to use `knitr::opts_knit$set(<SOMETHING>)` to modify the header-derived data structure from there).

Yet another option might be to move the top-level parameter `geometry` below the `bookdown::pdf_book` or `bookdown::pdf_document2` levels - but there appears to be no facility for such overrides at that level.

How would I go about rendering an option like `geometry` conditional on the output type?

Comment: Now escalated to the source ... https://github.com/rstudio/bookdown/issues/681

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your input.